# 2 bit right shift of a 32 bit unsigned integer

Tags: assembly, binary

How is one supposed to tackle the following question?

> Let N1 be an unsigned integer over 32 bits. Give the assembly code
>   allowing to realise the following operation:
>
> A right shift of 2 bit order of N1, but ONLY of the bits in an even
>   position as shown in the following illustration:
>
> [image]

P.S: What I tried to do was evaluate every bit if its index was even but I'm not sure that is the right way, or how it would be written in assembly.

Comment: Which assembly language? Anyway you can split the even and odd bits, shift the even bits, then put them back together: `((x & 0x55555555) >> 2) | (x & 0xAAAAAAAA)` and put the lsb in the carry flag somehow.

Comment: Sorry, for got to add that, IBM/360

Comment: thanks for typo correction hehehe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logic wise.

Get the even bits by `anding` with 55555555
Then `right shift` that, to give N1er2

Get the odd bits by `Anding` with AAAAAAAA to give N1o

The result would be N1er2 `Ored` with N1o

Comment: Are you sure about those masks though? I thought it was about even and odd bits, not even and odd "groups of two"

Comment: @harold No I messed up there fixing.

Comment: Thanks that was really helpful, clearly what I was doing was not correct haha

Comment: @TonyHopkinson It's the other way round. You get the even bits using 55555555h and the odd bits by using AAAAAAAAh.

Comment: @user3144770 Nope I made that mistake and then fixed it when it was pointed out by Harold 1111 & 1010 = 1010...

Comment: @TonyHopkinson harolds original comment beneath the question has the answer. Your masks (as pointed out by @user3144770) are wrong. Even bits are in positions 0, 2, 4, ... Your example _1111 & 1010 = 1010_  will produce the odd bits in positions 1, 3, ...

Comment: FFS guy had accepted the thing. Somebody has even formatted it. Did it ever occur to you to post a better answer?